# adding a utility namespace in JasmineJS

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm starting to modify a JasmineJS test suite, and there are some logging calls I want to clean up.  Specifically I want to add a `utilities.js` file in the directory of the test spec... and reference it throughout all my test specs.

There are now two test specs `testSuite1.spec.js` and `testSuite2.spec.js`, and one `page.js` which has a bunch of routines.

It seems this doesn't work.  Any idea why?

**testSuite1.spec.js**

```
var page = require('./page.js');
var testUtilities = require('./testUtilities.js');
var params = browser.params;

describe("App dashboard", function () {

browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
var params = browser.params;

describe("login", function () {

    it("should go to login page", function () {
        testUtilities.writeTitleToLog('Login');
        testUtilities.writeToLog("resizing window and going to home page");
```

**testUtilities.js**

```
var testUtilities = function () {
    "use strict";

    this.writeToLog = function (message, isTitleMessage) {
        if (typeof message !== 'string') {
            console.log(Date() + " TestSpec -- WARNING: messaged was not a string");
        }
        if (isTitleMessage) {
            console.log("\n" + Date() + " TestSpec - " + message.toUpperCase() + '\n');
        } else {
            console.log(Date() + " TestSpec —- " + message);
        }
    };

    this.writeTitleToLog = function (message) {
        this.writeToLog(message, true);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, from the code you've posted it looks like `testUtilities.js` doesn't export anything. Without that, `testUtilities` in your specs are going to be `undefined`. To fix this, you'll need to explicitly declare your exports:

```
exports.testUtilities = function () {
    "use strict";
     //...
};
```

Second thing that should be fixed: in your `testUtilities` you declare a function with a strict mode inside where some utility methods are added to `this`, but this is going to work only if you call it with a `new` keyword like a constructor:

```
var testUtilities = new (require('./testUtilities.js'))();
```

which arguably is not that elegant. Additionally, it would require always carrying about passing correct `this` to `writeTitleToLog()` as it uses `this` to lookup for `writeToLog()`.

To fix that, `testUtilities.js` could be rewritten to export a number of utility functions:

```
"use strict";

function writeToLog(message, isTitleMessage) {
    if (typeof message !== 'string') {
        console.log(Date() + " TestSpec -- WARNING: messaged was not a string");
    }
    if (isTitleMessage) {
        console.log("\n" + Date() + " TestSpec - " + message.toUpperCase() + '\n');
    } else {
        console.log(Date() + " TestSpec —- " + message);
    }
}

function writeTitleToLog(message) {
    writeToLog(message, true);
}

module.exports = {
    writeToLog: writeToLog,
    writeTitleToLog: writeTitleToLog
};
```

And then usage of it would be exactly same as in your question:

```
var testUtilities = require('./testUtilities.js');
describe("something", function () {
    testUtilities.writeTitleToLog("Something is being tested");
    it("should be ok to call test utilities", function () {
        testUtilities.writeToLog("Executing sanity check");
        expect(true).not.toBe(false);
    });
});
```

Or if you already use ES2015 syntax in your project, it could be simplified (in my opinion) with destructuring assignment's syntax sugar to this:

```
const {writeToLog, writeTitleToLog} = require('./testUtilities.js');
describe("something", function () {
    writeTitleToLog("Something is being tested");
    it("should be ok to call test utilities", function () {
        writeToLog("Executing sanity check");
        expect(true).not.toBe(false);
    });
});
```